# Why android system back button press is not handled in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, button, flutter-navigation

Why back button press doesn't trigger `onWillPop` in my screen? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**Ensure that you don't have multiple Scaffolds in your widgets**

if your `_body(context)` hold `scaffold`.. remove it.

also `WillPopScope` **returns future** so you should do like this according to your logic

```
return Future.value(false);
```

also make sure you are **passing MaterialApp** to the runApp method like this:

```
runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyFirstPage()));
```

Comment: if that solved your question mark question as answered.

Comment: all conditions you mentioned have no influence, you can check my repo if you want.

https://github.com/rockstar4095/multiplication_table/tree/develop

Comment: @YaroBest Which screen specifically are you having the issue with? We can't just crawl blindly through your entire repo looking for obscure bugs.